# Why r.map() is not a function?

Tags: angular

I made a class that is supposed to get "functionalities" of an user in json format from the db and then with these informations generate a dynamic menu to the client. The class is as follows:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FunctionalityService {

  private path: ApiPath;

  constructor(
    api: ApiService
  ) {
    this.path = // Suppose a correct path here
  }

  list(): Observable<Functionality[]> {

    return this.path
      .getJson<any[]>()
      .pipe(map(r => r.map(f => Functionality.get(f))));
  }
}
```

The problem is I get an error saying "r.map is not a function" when I run this, what's wrong?

Comment: `r` isn't an `Array`

Comment: r apparently is of type any[], which is an array, or am I wrong?

Comment: @CaioSchnepper you can tell the compiler all you want, but if getJson doesn't return an array, it will still fail

Comment: This is also weird because I can see the request made and a return of code 200 with the array inside

Comment: can you show the r value in console?

Comment: I can just get an Observable, no idea how to print its value middle function